# Problema de soma de frações em C#

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo

> Fazer um programa para calcular e exibir a soma dos “N” primeiros valores da sequência abaixo. O valor “N” será digitado (`TextBox`), deverá ser positivo, maior que zero, mas menor que cinquenta. Caso o valor não satisfaça a restrição, enviar mensagem de erro e solicitar o valor novamente. A sequência: 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5,... até N/(N+1)

Para resolvê-lo, criei um `Textbox` e um botão no Visual Studio, utilizando de C#.

Cheguei no seguinte código:

```
namespace SomaFracoes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int NSoma=0;
            double calculo =0;
            double number =0;

            if (int.TryParse(txtNum.Text, out NSoma) && NSoma <= 50 && NSoma > 0)
            {


                NSoma--;

                for (int i = 0; i < NSoma; i++)
                {

                    number =  Convert.ToDouble(i);
                    number++;
                    calculo += number /( number + 1);

                }

                MessageBox.Show(calculo.ToString("F"));

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Digite um número válido");


            }
            }

        }

    }
```

Porém não consigo ter a resposta certa (exemplo, se digitado 3 no `Textbox`, segundo meus cálculos deveria ser mostrado 1,91 no `MessageBox`) não sei onde está o problema deste código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí, começando pela interpretação do texto. Eu resolvi em 2 linhas (mudei para console para tornar universal e simplificar, mas é só mudar a contante ali pela variável do WinForms e voltar escrever na janela em vez do console):

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        if (int.TryParse("5", out var limite) && limite > 0 && limite < 50) for (var i = 1.0; i <= limite; i++) WriteLine($"{i/(i + 1):F2}");
        else WriteLine("Digite um número válido");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rNtqmx). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cd89LQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Fraction.cs).

Organizei um pouco melhor a condição, e mandei validar até 50 exclusivamente conforme o enunciado. Não tem porque diminuir 1 no limte digitado. Melhorei o nome da variável.

Aí eu comecei o laço já no 1 e como `double`, não tem porque converter e incrementar nada, nem criar tanta variável assim, ainda mais longe de onde elas são usadas.

O enunciado está um pouco esquisito, mas entendi que deve mostrar a sequência de dados. O que não está claro nele é se deve fazer a conta ou mostrar um texto com as frações, fui na conta porque você começou assim e faz algum sentido.